# Vertically align text

Tags: css, text, alignment, center

Im having problem vertically aligning a text with CSS. I have tried probably everything but it just doesnt want to work. You can see my demo jsfiddle demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcU7M/7/

```
.section {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

With this code it should work but something is wrong.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcU7M/7/

Comment: Don't avoid the requirements to use a jsfiddle link by putting false code in, instead you should just post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
.section {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zcU7M/1/)

Comment: Please check my updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcU7M/7/ . I included bootstraps css and js files. IM having the same problem locally, not text is aligned but its all stuck on the left.

Answer (score 1):

The `.section` needs the `display: table-cell`

```
.section {
    height: 200px;
    background:#ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display:table-cell;
}
```

The `display:table-cell` is what allows an element to have children vertically aligned, so it has to be on the parent to be able to have the children aligned vertically.

Here's a [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/zcU7M/4/).

Comment: Please check my updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcU7M/7/ . I included bootstraps css and js files. IM having the same problem locally, not text is aligned but its all stuck on the left.

Comment: @RichardMišenčík : ??? That demo looks like it's working correctly.  Please explain more.  I want to help.

Comment: The section doesnt span the full width. Its kind of stuck to the left side.

Comment: Add `.container{width:auto;}` to your CSS.  For some reason, you're `bootstrap.min.css` tries to set the width of `.container` to `1170px` and you need to override that.  See this [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/zcU7M/8/).

Comment: are you sure thats ok? Wont it break some code somewhere else, or something else? Could I somehow alter the markup so this would work?

Comment: You could put it in as inline style.  [Kind of like this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/zcU7M/9/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41777/discussion-between-richard-misencik-and-superscript)

Answer (score 1):

```
For a vertical paragraph align use that:

p { 
      height:200px;
      line-height:200px;
      text-align:center;
      vertical-align: middle; 
    }
```

JSFiddle example: [Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdc7a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the <p>-Tag  just adds some margin at the bottom. You can see this, when inspecting with firebug. Simply add a margin: 0 to your .section p selector:

```
.section p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcU7M/22/

Answer (score 0):

all credit goes to this link owner @Sebastian Ekström [Link](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/), please go through this.
see it in action [codepen](http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/kzEhe),
by reading above article I crated a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hegvLmee/1/) also.

With just 3 lines of CSS (excluding vendor prefixes) we can with the help of transform: translateY  vertically center whatever we want, even if we don’t know its height.

The CSS property transform is usally used for rotating and scaling elements, but with its translateY function we can now vertically align elements. Usually this must be done with absolute positioning or setting line-heights, but these require you to either know the height of the element or only works on single-line text etc.

So, to do this we write:

```
.element {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

That’s all you need. It is a similar technique to the absolute-position method, but with the upside that we don’t have to set any height on the element or position-property on the parent. It works straight out of the box, even in IE9!

To make it even more simple, we can write it as a mixin with its vendor prefixes: